# Tomcat thread waiting on and locking the same resource

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, concurrency, locks

Consider the following Java\Tomcat thread dump:

```python
"http-0.0.0.0-4080-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000019a2b000 nid=0x360e in Object.wait() [0x0000000040b71000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00002ab5565fe358> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked <0x00002ab5565fe358> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is this a deadlock? It seems that the same resource (`0x00002ab5565fe358`) is both `locked` and `waited on` - what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its more like an infinite wait(). It would have said something like id1 is BLOCKED on monitor owned by id2

Comment: OK I took a look at the source for JIoEndpoint.Worker. It is as I thought the await() method at line 453 is synchronized and there is an open call to it in the run() method at line 484.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer and add a solution so I can accept it?